# Decode function in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a condition like
if(someparam!=value1)
someparam=1
if(someparam!=value2)
someparam =2
Default value = 1

How to use decode function for this condition

Comment: what is expected result for something that is not value1 and not value2 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECODE(SomeParam, Value1, DECODE(SomeParam, Value2, 1, 2), 1)
```

but case is better:

```
case when someparam != Value1 then 1
    whene someparam != Value2 then 2
    else 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 decode(someparam, value2, 1, 2)
```

The whole comparison to value1 seems redundant, as it is only going to the default value anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> **DECODE**(SomeParam, someParam!=value1, 1,
>   someParam!=value2, 2, 1)

The default is the same as when assessing someparam! = Value1 therefore can simplify it like this:

> **DECODE**(SomeParam, someParam!=value2, 2, 1)

I hope this helps :-)